# Android animation to hide fragment during swipe to different tabs

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-animation

I am trying to build a user interface such that I have view pager with tabs. UI needs to have a fragment which appears at the bottom which needs to slide in and out as user moves between tabs.
  I am able to hide or show the "Sub Action Bar" by calling "setVisiblity" method on that fragment. What I am trying to do is animate the bottom fragment during the swipe action.

Here is the image to better explain my question:

[image: Screen layout]

BLUE: Action bar
  GREEN: ViewPager
  ORANGE: Sub Action bar that may only appear while user is in certain tabs and hide while in different tab.

[image: Swiping between tabs]

As the user is swiping to "Tab 2", "Sub Action Bar" needs to slide down.

[image: Tab2 Layout]
Since the User went to "Tab 2", "Sub Action Bar is now invisible"

Answer (score 1):

i m not sure but u may help you use sub-action bar property set gone in xml and when tab1 show it set to visible and on tab2 set to gone

Comment: Thanks kirti for your contribution. My question is about applying the animation during the swipe gesture. I am able to hide or make it visible while in each tab programmatically by calling "setVisibility" method on that view (fragment). but this is abrupt change. Instead I would like to have an animation.